# How to store user uploaded files in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am building a custom form (without using any plugin) that get data from users on the front-end, not from the admin area. One of the form element is a file field where users can upload multiple files.

What are the mechanism of storing user generated files in Wordpress? Are there any helper functions that allow developers to easily store files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing upload button you will get a file BLOB by using $_FILES

```
$file = $_FILES['filename'];
$filename = $file["tmp_name"]

$upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename, null, $file);

if (!$upload_file['error']) {
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_parent' => $parent_post_id,
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );

    //If you want to insert into a post or custom posttype, then make $parent_post_id = 0
    //Otherwise $parent_post_id = id of post/posttype
    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], $parent_post_id );
    if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload_file['file'] );
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $attachment_data );
    //1- get the url
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
    //2-get current logged in user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'uploaded_attachments', $url );
    }else{
        //Failed with message = $attachment_id->get_error_message()

    }
}else{
    //Error : file upload failed 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The wp api function to add the a new field to the user is "add_user_meta" function.

In my opinion you have to add a new custom field to the user using the function "add_user_meta". Then, you should add the uploaded file to the media library with the function "wp_insert_attachment".

Read the form values.

**1 - Add the uploaded file using the function "wp insert attachment".**

**2 - Add the field to user with the function "add_user_meta".**

**3 - Assign file the reference ID to the user field.**

These are the documentations links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment

Regards,
Ed.